# How to use an alias in Correlated subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
mysql> select * from instructor;

+-------+------------+------------+----------+
| ID    | name       | dept_name  | salary   |
+-------+------------+------------+----------+
| 10101 | Srinivasan | Comp. Sci. | 65000.00 |
| 12121 | Wu         | Finance    | 90000.00 |
| 15151 | Mozart     | Music      | 40000.00 |
| 22222 | Einstein   | Physics    | 95000.00 |
| 32343 | El Said    | History    | 60000.00 |
| 33456 | Gold       | Physics    | 87000.00 |
| 45565 | Katz       | Comp. Sci. | 75000.00 |
| 58583 | Califieri  | History    | 62000.00 |
| 76543 | Singh      | Finance    | 80000.00 |
| 76766 | Crick      | Biology    | 72000.00 |
| 83821 | Brandt     | Comp. Sci. | 92000.00 |
| 98345 | Kim        | Elec. Eng. | 80000.00 |
+-------+------------+------------+----------+
```

and I have a SQL statement like this

```
select name,salary,dept_name from instructor t1 
where salary > 
(
   select avg(salary) 
   from instructor t2
   group by dept_name   
   having t1.dept_name = t2.dept_name 
)
+-----------+----------+------------+
| name      | salary   | dept_name  |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Wu        | 90000.00 | Finance    |
| Einstein  | 95000.00 | Physics    |
| Califieri | 62000.00 | History    |
| Brandt    | 92000.00 | Comp. Sci. |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I want to add an **alias(dept_avg_salary)** in outer query but fails.....

```
select name,salary,dept_name,dept_avg_salary from instructor t1 
where salary > 
(
   select avg(salary) as dept_avg_salary
   from instructor t2
   group by dept_name
   having t1.dept_name = t2.dept_name 
)
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'dept_avg_salary' in 'field list'

can anybody tell me why and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference an alias like that.  Here's a better approach using a subquery with a `join`:

```
select t1.name, t1.salary, t1.dept_name, t2.dept_avg_salary
from instructor t1 join (
    select dept_name, avg(salary) dept_avg_salary
    from instructor
    group by dept_name) t2 on t1.dept_name = t2.dept_name
where t1.salary > t2.dept_avg_salary
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fb0e1/1)

Comment: thanks for your quick answer :) and can you tell why i cannot use alias like that?

Comment: from the out select's point of view.. it does not know anything about any information in inner selects in terms of columns...   out of scope.. so to speak.