# SQL Unknown P2 usage on Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query below:

```sql
INSERT INTO `permissions` (
  `name`,
  `display_name`,
  `module_id`,
  `parent_id`,
  `parent_name`,
  `is_main_menu`,
  `order`,
  `is_active`
)
VALUES
  (
    'appointment_type.index',
    "msg('lbl_appointment_type')",
    23,
    (SELECT
      p2.id
    FROM
      (SELECT
        *
      FROM
        permissions
      WHERE NAME = "setting.mentor_mentee") p2),
    "setting.mentor_mentee",
    0,
    1,
    1
  );
```

I am having trouble to understand portion below:

`(SELECT p2.id FROM (SELECT * FROM permissions WHERE NAME = "setting.mentor_mentee")p2)`

I am not sure what I am looking into. What is this `p2`? Please point me to right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It aliases the correlated subquery into something referable. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476301/how-to-use-an-alias-in-correlated-subquery)

Comment: It was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing nothing whatsoever.  You can phrase this as:

```
VALUES ('appointment_type.index', 'msg(''lbl_appointment_type'')', 23,
        (SELECT p.id
         FROM permissions p
         WHERE p.NAME = 'setting.mentor_mentee'
        ),
        'setting.mentor_mentee', 0, 1, 1
      )
```

Note the preference for single quotes.

In practice, I would recommend doing this using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO
    SELECT 'appointment_type.index', 'msg('lbl_appointment_type')', 23,
            p.id
            'setting.mentor_mentee', 0, 1, 1
    FROM permissions p
    WHERE NAME = 'setting.mentor_mentee';
```

Why did someone write the code with the subquery?  Presumably, the person who wrote the query confused `INSERT` with `UPDATE`/`DELETE`.  Those do not allow subqueries to reference the table being modified -- except using a hack like double subqueries.  The normal solution is not a double subquery but using `JOIN`.

This is not an issue with `INSERT` because conceptually the subquery returns its result set before the rows are inserted.